# Color the row in combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm having trouble with finding the solution for the problem, namely I had an idea to color each row/column of combobox with different colors, depending on the area, but i cannot find any clues or hints or instructions to do so. the app is pretty simple

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230"/>
```

this is my XAML combobox, which i fill from the code:

```
SortedList<int, string> AreaList = new SortedList<int, string>();
        AreaList.Add(1, "Agriculture");
        AreaList.Add(2, "Forestry");
        AreaList.Add(3, "Fruits");
        AreaList.Add(4, "Food");
        AreaList.Add(5, "Metals");
        AreaList.Add(6, "Mining");
        AreaList.Add(7, "Electricity");
        AreaList.Add(8, "Building Contracts");
        AreaList.Add(9, "Transport");
        AreaList.Add(10, "Alcohol");
        AreaList.Add(11, "Information Technologies");
        AreaList.Add(12, "Health And Social Services");
        AreaList.Add(13, "Art and Entertainement");
        AreaList.Add(14, "Hospitality Business");
        AreaList.Add(15, "Education");
        AreaList.Add(16, "Real Estate");
        AreaList.Add(17, "Sales");
        AreaList.Add(18, "Architecture");
        AreaList.Add(19, "Engineering");
        AreaList.Add(20, "Wholesale");
        AreaList.Add(21, "Other");

        comboBox1.ItemsSource = AreaList.ToList();
        comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
        comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
```

each of these items have their color in another window, but i would like to show those colors in the combobox, the background of "Agriculture" row/column should be green etc.
Is there a solution to this, or do i have to redo it all over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an ItemContainerStyle with a DataTrigger for each value that maps to a colour:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="Agriculture">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="Forestry">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <!-- and so on-->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

You may also want to read this:

**Changing the background colour of a ComboBox in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/

Comment: actually this is it, tnx alot for this, I'm still learning WPF, and i can find my way in the code, but XAML is still a mistery, tnx for patience :)

Comment: oh, just crossing my mind, for future reference, is it possible to add like a square at the end of, for example, agriculture column, colored green, just the square? You don't have to answer if the question is stupid xD

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ItemContainerStyle and Converter

```
 public class StringToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (((KeyValuePair<int, string>)value).Value.ToString() == "Agriculture")
                return Brushes.Green;
            //and so on or other ways to get the color
            return Brushes.Transparent;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and XAML goes as follows,

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:StringToColorConverter x:Key="StringToColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid >
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230">
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}">

                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```